# apply transition property when i apply a class

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to slide the div from right to left when a class is applied to a div. I tried the below code. But it did not work. Is there anything wrong?

```
.dealer-info {
    left:100%;
    -webkit-transition-property: left; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

.dealer-info.dealer-show {
    left:0%;
}
```

Comment: Why a different value for webkit?

Answer (score 0):

Please add position as `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`, depending on your requirements.

```
.dealer-info {

left:100%;
position: relative; /* or absolute depending on your use case */

  -webkit-transition-property: left; /* Safari */
-webkit-transition-duration: 100s; /* Safari */
transition-property: left;
transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

.dealer-info.dealer-show{

```
left:0%;
}
```

Comment: Mike. It did not work...When its on same class it works. When on class change it does not.

Comment: do you want the div to animate when `.dealer-show` class is added to it?